# Как получить state.data определенного юзера в хэндлере - aiogram 3

Tags: aiogram-3.x

Как получить данные state конкретного юзера в хендлере, который уже вне цепочки состояний?
Я получаю данные юзера и либо одобряю его, либо отклоняю. И потом мне нужны эти данные в хендлере

```
@main_reg_router.callback_query(ApproveDeclineCallback.filter(F.result == True))
async def callback_approve(call: CallbackQuery, bot: Bot, callback_data: dict, user: BotUser) -> None:
```

Т.е. напрямую я уже не могу получить состояние юзера, т.к. этот хендлер обрабатывает мое нажатие кнопки.
У меня Aiogram 3